# Reinitialize library when new data is available

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-tracker

I'm currently developing a Meteor application where I use the video.js-Library.

I have the following template:

```
template(name='foo')
  .video.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-16by9
    with richMediaContent
      video#video.video-js.vjs-default-skin.vjs-big-play-centered(controls='' preload='auto')
        source(src='{{video.videoUrl}}' type='video/mp4')
        p.vjs-no-js {{i18n 'videoTagNotSupported'}}
```

Initializing the video.js-Library after the template is rendered works fine.

```
Template.foo.onRendered ->
  videojs document.getElementsByClassName('video-js')[0], {}
```

But the videojs-Library is not reinitialized if the same template is rendered with a different video (with a different richMediaContent).

I've already tried to move the video-Part in an own template and included it in the foo-Template so that the onRendered-Call should get called every time a new video is loaded. But this doesn't seem to work.

Do you have any idea how I can reinitialize the library if the video changes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**New answer**

Indeed, when your route changes but uses the same template, the said template does not get rendered again, therefore your js plugin call will not trigger a second time. What you can do instead is call your js plugin in an [`onAfterAction`](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#available-hook-methods) call, within your route definition:

```
Router.route('/video/:_id', {
  name: 'video_page',
  template: 'foo',
  // ...
  onAfterAction: function () {
    videojs document.getElementsByClassName('video-js')[0], {}
  }
});
```

**Previous answer**

I think you are looking for the almighty `this.autorun`. At the end of your onRendered function, it should look like this (I type it in pure javascript)

```
this.autorun(function () {
  var video = Session.get("video"); // reactive data
  videojs document.getElementsByClassName('video-js')[0], {}
});
```

The idea is that the first line must include, within the autorun function, a way to get your reactive data. In that case, I use the Session which is reactive. Collections are also reactive, so another way would be something like `Videos.findOne();`. This will depend on how *you* get that `video` element.

What this does is that any time the reactive data changes, the callback for `this.autorun` will run again, and your video plugin will be reset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also had the same idea. unfortunately the autorun-Function is not called when the data (in this case the document of the collection changes). Here's the code:

Template.foo.onRendered ->
  @autorun ->
    video = Videos.findOne()
    console.log application
    videojs document.getElementsByClassName('video-js')[0], {}

Comment: My guess is that the Videos collection does not really change then... does it? Also you may need to call your plugin one first time before this.autorun, in order to pre-set the plugin before any change in the collection

Comment: thank you for your answer! The problem is that all Videos are already available on the client (so nothing gets added to the collection afterwards). On the right side there are related videos and on the link side is the currently selected video (the id of the video is contained) in the URL. So I need to rerun the Video.js initialize-Code when the URL changes / the  video on the left side changes.

Comment: Ah, I see! The template doesn't change but the route does then? At least the params. Then maybe put your videojs call on the `onAfterAction` event of your video route in your iron router configuration. [Look here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-specific-options) for usage. Will edit my answer shortly.